# Adding and Subtracting Dates and Wrong Calculations

Tags: excel, excel-2007

[image]

I'm Working on a ticket tracking excel sheet and what I am trying to do is calculate average ticket time but take into inconsideration Hold time.  So if a ticket is open on let's say, Dec 3, 2021, but was put on hold from Dec 4th-6th, and then the ticket was closed on the 8th so that would be a total of only 3 days in my K Column for Ticket age.  I am currently using this as the formula =SUM(J62-I62-L62) but showing the answer as 4 instead of 3

Comment: `=H62-G62-(J62-I62)`

Answer (score 1):

answer is =H62-G62-(J62-I62) .. Thanks scott